# Historic data on UK roads 1950-2010

Tags: geospatial, uk

I'm looking for data about roads in the UK. [OS Open Roads](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-roads.html) is a great spatial dataset with detailed shapefiles, but it doesn't contain **temporal information**. I would like to find a dataset with roads from the 1950s onward. For each road, I would like to know when it was built (and closed, if it doesn't exist anymore). I'm particularly interested in the development of the motorway network in the UK. Does such dataset exist?

Comment: You might be able to find a potential data source by researching this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roads_in_the_United_Kingdom)?